# Should stackoverflow provide facility to directly migrate question without close?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, migration

Sometimes, developers are not sure about asking question on any of the stackexchange application. This results in close of the question. But, however, this requires to wait till the complete close of question to migrate it.

Isn't there a requirement for Administrator of the Question (who had asked) to migrate without close ?

Answer (score 2):

♦ moderators have binding votes and can migrate without the standard-wait-for-5-people-to-vote routine.

Answer (score 1):

You can flag such posts for moderator attention if you feel they should be migrated immediately.